# python file output bugs

Tags: python

So I have to take the numbers from a certain file
containing:

```
1 5
2 300
3 3
9 155
7 73
7 0
```

Multiply them and add them to a new file
I used the script under here but for some reason, it now gives a syntax error.

```
f=open('multiply.txt')
f2=open('resulted.txt','w')

while True:
    line=f.readline()
    if len(line)==0:
        break
    line=line.strip()
    result=line.split(" ")
    multiply=int(result[0])*int(result[1])
    multiply=str(multiply)
    answer=print(result[0],"*",result[1],"=",multiply)
f2.write(str(multiply))           
f.close()
f2.close()
```

i found out that f2.write(multiply) works
but i get all the answers as 1 string (5600913955110)
how do i get it to be 1 good text file and give the right calculation

### Update:

```
f=open('multiply.txt')
f2=open('result.txt','w')
while True:
    line=f.readline()
    if len(line)==0:
        break
    line=line.strip()
    result=line.split(" ")
    multiply=int(result[0])*int(result[1])
    multiply=str(multiply)
    answer=print(result[0],"*",result[1],"=",multiply)
    answer=str(answer)
    f2.write(str(answer))
    f2.write(str(multiply))        
f.close()
f2.close()
```

output:

```
None5None600None9None1395None511None0
```

Comment: Make sure your parentheses balance.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses here:  `f2.write(str(answer)`

Comment: Also, `answer=print(...` The `print` function does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the code you have this line:

```
f2.write(str(answer)
```

notice there is not a `)` at the end and you have two `(` in the line.
try this:

```
f2.write(str(answer))
```

Also the name of the post sounds like its provoking opinion response. Try to change it so it doesn't mention your friend but the problem at hand.

Comment: i have changed my post.
but this still gives me only a string of numbers as a result.

Comment: i answered your new question in a new response

Comment: also when you write code, try to do small steps. this helps minimize the debugging time.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, there are **escape sequences**. Escape sequences allow you to do many things. in your case you need to add the escape sequence

```py
"\n"
```

this will add a new line onto each thing you append to the file.

like this:

```py
    answer=str(result[0])+"*"+str(result[1])+"="+str(multiply)
    print(answer)
    f2.write(str(answer)+"\n")
```

Comment: ah okay i tried adding the '\n' this helped getting the output under eachother yes.
but is it possible to add the output from answer=print(result[0],"*",result[1],"=",multiply) in the file
so in the result it will give the whole calculation
5*1=5
2*300=600
etc etc

Comment: i fixed my answer, sorry i did not comment when i was done

Comment: yes this works perfectly thank you so much!
this is the final script
f=open('multiply.txt')
f2=open('results.txt','w')

while True:
    line=f.readline()
    if len(line)==0:
        break
    line=line.strip()
    result=line.split(" ")
    multiply=int(result[0])*int(result[1])
    answer=str(result[0])+"*"+str(result[1])+"="+str(multiply)
    f2.write(str(answer)+"\n")
    
            
f.close()
f2.close()

Comment: if it works so well, please mark it as the answer. This helps me out a lot. ;)